# Pass product attributes in add_to_cart function in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product with attribute called Subjects (i.e. Biology). It is not a variant, because one product can have multiple subjects selected.
Now I want to use add_to_cart function to add that product into cart with one or more attributes - how to do that? I know that code is:

```
add_to_cart(
    $product_id = 0,
    $quantity = 1,
    $variation_id = 0,
    $variation = array(),
    $cart_item_data = array()
);
```

But when I use it like that:

```
$atr = array();
$atr['Subjects'] = 'Biology'; 
WC()->cart->add_to_cart('111',1,0,$atr,null);
```

It only add the product without attributes. When I choose attributes on product page, they are pass to cart after add to cart button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific array or use js(declare php in variables in js).

Comment: Ok, but what should it look like?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).